# Python Pandas Convert 10 digit datetime to a proper date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, data-conversion, python-datetime

I have an excel file which contains date format in 10 digit.

For example,
Order Date as 1806825282.731065,
Purchase Date as 1806765295

Does anyone know how to convert them to a proper date format such as **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm** or **dd/mm/yyyy**? Any date format will be fine.

I tried **pd.to_datetime** but does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: What would be the dates for the examples above?

Comment: I think you should use something like: `pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], unit='s')`

Comment: That's probably be [unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Comment: @QuangHoang. Yes but the converted date is `Timestamp('2027-04-04 07:54:42.731065088')`. Strange for an Order Date :-)

Comment: I am not sure if the original timestamp is unix. I know the very original data source is a SAS dataset and the person just forwarded me in Excel thinking it is easier for me to process in python. Thanks!

Comment: The actual date should be  Apr 02, 2017

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], unit='s') is very close but somehow the years are inflated.  Should be 2017 but became 2027...

Comment: It's because [the epoch is different](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_035/ds2pg/n02zpqz4j5u3j9n1t0i95ncqep5g.htm), 1960, not 1970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS timestamp are stored in seconds from 1960-1-1:

```
import pandas as pd

origin = pd.Timestamp('1960-1-1')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order Date': [1806825282.731065],
                   'Purchase Date': [1806765295]})

df['Order Date'] = origin + pd.to_timedelta(df['Order Date'], unit='s')
df['Purchase Date'] = origin + pd.to_timedelta(df['Purchase Date'], unit='s')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                     Order Date       Purchase Date
0 2017-04-03 07:54:42.731065035 2017-04-02 15:14:55
```

From [The Essential Guide to SAS Dates and Times](https://www.sas.com/storefront/aux/en/spessguidedatetime/66300_excerpt.pdf)

> SAS has three separate counters that keep track of dates and times. The date counter started
> at zero on January 1, 1960. Any day before 1/1/1960 is a negative number, and any day
> after that is a positive number. Every day at midnight, the date counter is increased by one.
> The time counter runs from zero (at midnight) to 86,399.9999, when it resets to zero. The last
> counter is the datetime counter. This is the number of seconds since midnight, January 1, 1960. Why January 1, 1960? One story has it that the founders of SAS wanted to use the
> approximate birth date of the IBM 370 system, and they chose January 1, 1960 as an easy-
> to-remember approximation.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
(pd.to_timedelta(1806825282, unit='s') + pd.to_datetime('1960-1-1'))
```

or

```
(pd.to_timedelta(df['Order Date'], unit='s') + pd.to_datetime('1960-1-1'))
```

Comment: Just found out that you can use the `origin` argument of `to_datetime()`, so a clearer way to convert the date is to do `pd.to_datetime(1806825282, unit='s',origin='1960-1-1')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```py
# Convert the 10-digit datetime to a datetime object
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], unit='s')

# Format the datetime object to the desired format
df['date_column'] = df['date_column'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

Or if you want a one-liner:

```py
df['date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_column'], unit='s').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

According to The Pandas Documentation Link:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

**Code**

```python
>>> pd.to_datetime(1674518400, unit='s')
Timestamp('2023-01-24 15:16:45')

>>> pd.to_datetime(1674518400433502912, unit='ns')
Timestamp('2023-01-24 15:16:45.433502912')

# you can use template
df[DATE_FIELD]=(pd.to_datetime(df[DATE_FIELD],unit='ms'))
```